# @media query only work on that width only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, media, responsive

i write css for responsive at 768px but that design only show 768 only less that width my style was collapsed

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .logo {
    flex: 0 0 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .header-middle-box .col-md-3 {
    flex: 0 0 33%;
    max-width: 33%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) {
  .header-middle-box .col-md-3 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: So, whats your question?

Comment: learn here about ` @media only screen and (max-height:..)`:http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/height-based-media-queries.php

Comment: my media query for 768 only work on 768px less than 768 like 767,765 until 555 that style was not applied, i need to apply style 768px unitl 556

Comment: @Riyas Ahamed - Have you tried media (max-width:768px) and (min-width:556px) ?

Comment: yes but not working

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

i Just add separate media query for that particular width
@media only screen and (min-width: 556px) and (max-width: 768px) {}

and write custom css for that width :) thnx for your kind reply

-Riyas